# "A Simple Proof of Zorn's Lemma" article. (explanation of a step)

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

There is a short proof of Zorn's lemma by J.W.Lewin:
[A Simple Proof of Zorn's Lemma.pdf](https://digitalcommons.kennesaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2161&context=facpubs)

Summary:

I don't understand this step:
"Therefore if z is the least member of
$A\setminus P(B, y)$, we have $P(A, z) = P(B, y)$."

I'm interested in both  inclusions from left to right and from right to left.

---

A subset A of X is conforming if the following two conditions hold:

1. The order $<$ is a well order of the set A.
2. For every element $x\in A$, we have $x = f(P(A, x))$.

**Theorem** 
 If A and B are conforming subsets of X and $A\neq B$, then one of these two sets is an initial segment of the other.

**Proof** We may assume that $A\setminus B\neq\emptyset$. Define x to be the least member of
 $A\setminus B$. Then $P(A, x) \subseteq B$. We claim that $P(A, x) = B$. To obtain a contradiction,
 assume that $B\setminus P(A, x)\neq\emptyset$, and define y to be the least member of
 $B\setminus P(A, x)$. Given any element $u\in P(B, y)$ and any element $v\in A$ such that
 $v < u$, it is clear that $v \in P(B, y)$. Therefore if z is the least member of
 $A\setminus P(B, y)$, we have $P(A, z) = P(B, y)$. (???)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P(A,z)\subseteq P(B,y):$

if $\alpha\in P(A,z),$ then $\alpha\in A$ and $\alpha<z$ so $\alpha$ is in $A$ but $\textit{not}$ in $A\setminus P(B,y)$  (by definition of $z$), so in fact $\alpha\in P(B,y).$

$P(B,y)\subseteq P(A,z):$

if $\alpha\in P(B,y),$ then $\alpha\in B$ and $\alpha<y$ so $\alpha\in P(A,x)$ (by definition of $y$). Now, $\alpha \neq z$ (because $z\notin P(B,y)$). On the other hand, if $z<\alpha$, then since $\alpha\in P(B,y),$ we have $z\in P(B,y)$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, we have that $\alpha<z$ and $\alpha\in A.$ That is, $\alpha\in P(A,z).$

Comment: The only one step I don't understand. It is clearly proved that $z\notin B$ by $(z<y)$(transitivity z<a and a<y) and def of z. Now, how to show that $z\in B$? (In order to prove $z\in P(B,y)$)

Comment: I hope I added details to your answer in my answer, @Mathematleta . Maybe there exist a shorter proof. Our proofs of this particular case are identical, aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

Here I want to clarify part of the 
@Matematleta's proof which took some of my time.

> On the other hand, if $<$, then since $\in (,)$, we have
>   $\in (,)$, which is a contradiction.

We assume that $<$.

1) From $\in A\setminus (,)$, we obtain $z\in A \land [z\notin B\lor z\geqslant y]$

2) The second OR-case $z\geqslant y $ implies contradiction:
$z\geqslant y >\alpha>z$. That means that $z\notin B$.

3) $z \in A \land z\notin B$ implies $z\in A\setminus B$. 
y is the least element of $A\setminus B$. So $y\leqslant z$.

4)Then $z<\alpha<x\leqslant z$ - contradiction.

That means that the assumption $<$ is false.

p.s. Proof of the 4th proposition:
$\alpha < x$ here is from $\alpha\in P(A,x)$. 
In it's turn, this is from $\alpha\in B$ and $\alpha\notin B\setminus P(A,x)$. Proposition $\alpha\notin B\setminus P(A,x)$ is true because $\alpha\in B\setminus P(A,x)$ leads to a contradiction: $y\leqslant \alpha< y$.

Comment: Actually, $x$ is the least element of $A \setminus B$ right? Not $y$. The conclusion would be the same though... And thanks for this clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Actually this proof is not correct!

Suppose that X is a partial order under ≤. Let Low(A) and Up(A) be respectively the sets of all strict lower bounds and all strict upper bounds of a subset A of X; and let P(A, x) be all strict predecessors of x in A, i. e. A ∩ Low({x}).

Let *g* a choice function that assigns to every non-empty set one of its elements; and let  *f* be a function that assigns to every chain C in X the strict upper bound *f*(C) = *g*(Up(C)).

Now suppose that x and y ∈ X are incomparable (not x ≤ y and not y ≤ x) and that A = {x} and B = {y} and that *g*(the union of A and Up(A)) = x and *g*(the union of B and Up(B)) = y. So x = *f*(P(A,x)) and y = *f*(P(B,y)).

Now the sets A = {x} and B = {y} are conforming as defined in Lewin’s paper, because both are well-ordering and the second condition holds for both. But we supposed that x and y are incomparable; so are the sets A = {x} and B = {y}. So the whole lemma in the bottom of the first page of the paper is incorrect.

Comment: Two sets $A = \{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$, with $a\neq b$, cannot be both conforming, because the choice function will select for at most one of $a$ and $b$ among $X$, which is the set of strict upper bounds of the empty set.