# Question regarding a step in a proof of Zorn's Lemma

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'm trying to understand a [proof](https://digitalcommons.kennesaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2161&context=facpubs) of Zorn's Lemma. I can follow most of it, but there are a couple of points that I have not been able to comprehend:

1. Why is $z\leq x$?

2. Why is $P(B,y)=P(A,z)$? I can understand that $z$ is also the minimal element of $A-P(A,z)$, but that doesn't seem to get me to the equality.

I would appreciate any help.

---

[image]

Comment: For the first question, $P(B,y)$ is a subset of $B$, and so $\min A\setminus P(B,y)\leq \min A\setminus B$.

Comment: Here is the second question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119417/a-simple-proof-of-zorns-lemma-article-explanation-of-a-step